# Android - Application ui appearing larger in size on tablet as well as emulator

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am developing a application for android platform. The problem i am facing is the resolution of the ui is very large when i run the application on android device as well as on emulator. However it looks fine when running on browser. Earlier all was fine the problem arise few days after i updated project's build.xml file in accordance to the android-sdk. But i don't think the problem is because of that as UI didn't appeared large in size soon after the changes. i am not getting why UI is appearing large in size on tablet but not on browser.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Neeraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that an Image will look smaller on Higher resolution, and larger in lower resolution. Its simple maths. Again, browser may auto-resize the UI component according to browser preferences.

```
I suggest You to TEST WITH REAL DEVICES.
```

Comment: I have tested the application on Asus tab.I don't think its the problem of device resolution as earlier ui components were appearing fine but i don't know why those are appearing very large in size.

Comment: Hi, what are the UI components and which browser are you looking at?
I need more details and cleaner idea of the UI and code to go forward.